# Javascript DOM: What is the recommended way to search a child element in HTMLDivElements how it does document.getElementById?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When i search for a element by example by Id, I use the well know method `getElementById` like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="my-first-div">
    <div class="anotherDiv">
        <button id="main-btn"> </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
const mainDiv = document.getElementById("my-first-div");
const mainButton = mainDiv.querySelector("#main-btn");
//const mainButton = mainDiv.getElementById("main-btn"); //this doesn't work
```

So, the only way for find a child inside of a div is using `querySelector` method that in this basic example works fine, but for huge HTML markup it's more slow compared with the `document.getElementById`. See https://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector/11

My question is:

**Exists a better way for find child elements by id (or class, or tagName) without use querySelector for HTMLDivElement?**

Comment: why don't you want to use `querySelector`? That seems like the obvious solution here.

Comment: If it's because of speed you are definitely prematurely optimising there.

Comment: Your jsPerf is flawed BTW. Of course `querySelector` is slower it's not a good compassion to use it to find by id and then compare it against `getElementById`. `getElementById` is obviously highly optimised to find ids. This doesn't mean `querySelector` is slow, it's just slower to find elements by ids. But you can **only** find elements by id using `getElementById`. So it's totally unflexible, that's what `querySelector` is for. Basically you comparing apples with oranges and saying an orange is a terrible apple....

Comment: I understand your point, thank your for the guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other JavaScript methods that are "equivalent" to a single facet of `querySelector()` and theoretically should be faster since these methods do one thing only.

- [**.getElementsByClassName('X')[0]**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)
- [**.getElementsByName('X')[0]**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)
- [**.getElementsByTagName('X')[0]**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)

Normally these methods will collect all of whatever they are designed to collect and return a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) (an array-like object that is "live", meaning that if anything is added or removed, or changed in some way, it will automatically comply to said changes.) Notice the bracket notation `[0]`. This will return the first element of a document (or element) just like `.querySelector()`.

Also added some [HTMLElement Interfaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) for [`<table>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableCellElement) and [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection).

### Demo

```js
var gTagName = document.getElementsByTagName('ASIDE')[0];
var qTagName = document.querySelector('ASIDE');

var gName = document.getElementsByName('TEXT')[0];
var qName = document.querySelector('[name=TEXT]');

var gClass = document.getElementsByClassName('h')[0];
var qClass = document.querySelector('.h');

var qAttribute = document.querySelector('[href]');

qTagName.style.border = '3px solid blue';
qName.style.backgroundColor = 'cyan';
qClass.style.backgroundColor = 'darkblue';
qAttribute.style.color = 'midnightblue';

gTagName.style.backgroundColor = 'tomato';
gName.style.border = '3px solid red';
gClass.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';

var cForm = document.forms[0];
var cFields = cForm.elements;
for (var F of cFields) {
  F.style.border = '3px dashed brown';
}
cFields[1].value = 'HTMLFormControlsCollection';
cFields[1].style.transform = 'scale(2,2)';

var cTable = document.querySelector('table');
var cRows = cTable.rows;
var cCells = cRows[0].cells
cCells[2].textContent = 'This cell\'s just got content';
cCells[2].style.color = 'red';
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px dashed red
}

td {
  border: 1px solid blue
}

input {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='a'>&lt;DIV&gt;ISION a
  <div class='b'>&lt;DIV&gt;ISION b
    <table>
      <caption>&lt;TABLE&gt; get by HTMLTableCollection</caption>
      <tr>
        <td>TABLE DATA</td>
        <td>TABLE DATA</td>
        <td>TABLE DATA</td>
        <td>TABLE DATA</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class='c'>&lt;DIV&gt;ISION c
      <input name='TEXT' value='&lt;INPUT&gt; get by NAME'>
      <div class='d'>&lt;DIV&gt;ISION d
        <div class='e'>&lt;DIV&gt;ISION e
          <a href='#/'>&lt;A&gt;NCHOR get by [ATTRIBUTE]</a>
          <div class='f'>&lt;DIV&gt;ISION f
            <form><input value='&lt;INPUT&gt;'>
              <input value='&lt;INPUT&gt;'>
              <input value='&lt;INPUT&gt;'>
            </form>
            <div class='g'>&lt;DIV&gt;ISION g
              <aside>&lt;ASIDE&gt; get by TAGNAME</aside>
              <div class='h'>&lt;DIV&gt;ISION h get by .CLASS
                <div class='i'>&lt;DIV&gt;ISION i
                  <div class='j'>&lt;DIV&gt;ISION j

                  </div>

                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

I just noticed that you were already aware of `document.querySelector` - use it until it becomes too slow for you. Just because it's slower than `document.getElementById` doesn't mean it's not still ridiculously fast.

Like one of the commentors pointed out, don't optimize prematurely.

As an answer to you question, no the browser exposes no other usable API that is faster than these APIs to get DOM elements and I imagine that all of the `getElement(s)By` methods probably internally route to a `querySelector` method with a flag to return the first or all of the matched nodes.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

[`document` also contains the `querySelector` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```
const mainDiv = document.getElementById("my-first-div");
const mainButton = mainDiv.querySelector("#main-btn");
```

is the same as:

```
const mainButton = document.querySelector('#my-first-div #main-btn');
```

That being said, if `main-btn` is an `id`, then it's unique so you can just do:

```
const mainButton = document.getElementById('main-btn');
```

Comment: For some reason the OP states he doesn't want to use query selector. This seems a bit of a bizarre requirement but this doesn't actually answer his question.

Comment: `getElementById('#main-btn')` no need of `#` if you are lookinf for `main-btn` id

Answer (score -1):

try

```
document.getElementsByClassName('.class')
document.getElementsByTagName('div')
```

though getElementById is the quickest of the 3

the more specific you are with your classes the easier they will be to find

Comment: no need of `.class`, you need to give only `class` for `getElementsByClassName`